# Codeigniter MySQL table update

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables as follows in my Codeigniter Project, by joining budget_id

## finance_budget Table

```
+-----------+-------------+--------------+-----------------+
| budget_id | budget_date |    amount    | transfer_status |
+-----------+-------------+--------------+-----------------+
|         1 | 2020-03-10  |  500,000.00  | Pending         |
|         2 | 2020-03-11  |  600,000.00  | Pending         |
|         3 | 2020-03-12  |  400,000.00  | Pending         |
|         4 | 2020-03-13  |  200,000.00  | Pending         |
+-----------+-------------+--------------+-----------------+
```

## finance_budget_issue Table

```
+-----+-----------+-------------+--------------+-----------------+
| id  | budget_id | budget_date |    amount    | transfer_status |
+-----+-----------+-------------+--------------+-----------------+
| 100 |         1 | 2020-03-10  |  250,000.00  | Approved        |
| 101 |         1 | 2020-03-10  |  250,000.00  | Approved        |
| 102 |         2 | 2020-03-11  |  300,000.00  | Pending         |
| 103 |         2 | 2020-03-11  |  150,000.00  | Pending         |
| 104 |         2 | 2020-03-11  |  150,000.00  | Pending         |
+-----+-----------+-------------+--------------+-----------------+
```

finance_budget is the Master Table & finance_budget_issue is the Details Table. A view is used to insert records by master-details concept to the tables and that is working perfectly. After adding records to the tables my model function is used to change the transfer_status from "Pending" to "Approved". Controller & Model as follows :

## Controller

```
public function approveIssues($id){
        $this->checkPermissions('add', 'pendingIssues');
        if(empty($id)){
            redirect('budget/pendingIssue');
        }

        if($this->Budget_model->approveIssues($id)){
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Allocation Approved successfully ..!!');
            redirect('budget/pendingIssue');
        }else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Error ...!!!');
            redirect('budget/pendingIssue');
        }
    }
```

## Model

```
 function approveIssues($id)
        {

            $this->db->update('finance_budget_issue', array('transfer_status'=>'Approved'), array('id' => $id));
            if ($this->db->affected_rows()) {                  

                return true;
            }
            return false;

        }
```

The records of the finance_budget_issue table are displayed in the Approve view. Therefore, the transfer_status of finance_budget_issue table is changing using the above controller & model. This is also working fine.

But I want to change the transfer_status of finance_budget table as "Approved" when executing the above model function. And the output should be as follows : (ex:-budget_id=1)

```
+-----------+-------------+--------------+-----------------+
| budget_id | budget_date |    amount    | transfer_status |
+-----------+-------------+--------------+-----------------+
|         1 | 2020-03-10  |  500,000.00  | Approved        |
|         2 | 2020-03-11  |  600,000.00  | Pending         |
|         3 | 2020-03-12  |  400,000.00  | Pending         |
|         4 | 2020-03-13  |  200,000.00  | Pending         |
+-----------+-------------+--------------+-----------------+
```

For the operations of budget_id 2,3 & 4 should be as same as budget_id 1.

How can I change my code to do the expected result? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

**CODE**

```
function approveIssues($id) {
    $this->db->update('finance_budget', array('transfer_status'=>'Approved'), array('id' => $id));
    if ($this->db->affected_rows()) {                  
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @ T.Maharani. But transfer_status of finance_budget_issue table should be also changed as "Approved" when performing the function for the same budget_id

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.